# CreateJS published Movieclip divided to four

Tags: createjs

i have 200 image that shows body as a animation. just 200 image continuously. when i create html version of it by using CS6 CreateJS toolkit, i got that output. When it plays it divide screen to 4.

Does anyone have any suggestion.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone getting this issue its because currently ToolKit For CreateJS doesn't support transformations on bitmap fills.